# Error while loading shared libraries:libWFC.so

Tags: raspberry-pi3

When I tried installing `rplay` on my Raspberrypi 3b, 
this error occured to me

> Error while loading shared libraries:libWFC.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can someone help me?